# How do I disable the "responsive" grid in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So the responsive grid for bootstrap looks horrible for my site. When you shrink the window, everything gets smushed together and the navbar collapses into three rows (I disabled the responsive-collapsing navbar).

I tried deleting bootstrap-responsive.css but it still does that "fluid live grid collapsing" thing. It's driving me crazy.

How can I set a minimum width for the navbar and the entire page? So that everything doesn't get pushed together and you have to use the horizontal scroll bar to navigate the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing the **bootstrap-responsive.css** should provide you the behavior which you desire.  All the **span*** classes are explicit width in regular Bootstrap as long as you are using `row` and not `row-fluid` in the parent containers. The `row` class does not provide any width constraints, and none are made on the `<body>` either.  However, the `container` class does have an explicit width of 940px in standard **bootstrap.css**.

Comment: Ah, I realized why it didn't work once I deleted it. The bootstrap-responsive.css contents were also in the bootstrap.css file. I commented out the responsive parts and it's working. Is this normal? Why would they have a responsive.css file if it's already included in the base one?

Comment: You didn't download that file from the [Twitter Bootstrap front page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I know that some unofficial CDN's, like BootstrapCDN, combine the plain and responsive, but the default download on the official site does not. Or perhaps you used [the Customize page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)?

Comment: Ah, I think I used the Customize page. Makes sense. Thank you!