# How to make a layout not auto adjust on windows resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on [a website](http://www.nosquebecois.com) and when I resize the window, the whole content gets adjusted (see image 1).

How can I remove the auto-adjust and make it like the image 2 ?

Btw, i'm using bootstrap

1. [image: Wrong navbar]
2. [image: To be navbar]

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219760/how-do-i-disable-the-responsive-grid-in-bootstrap

Comment: it's not a duplicate question, since i'm not using the bootstrap's responsible css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `min-width: 1000px;` or however much you want, on your `div.container`, so that it doesn't break when the width of the elements ends up bigger than of the wrapper itself.

Comment: thank you got it working for my header, now i'll for my content. + 1