# Rails/bootstrap - Trying to center elements inside a span, but spans center when shrinking viewport

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying entries in a group of spans in a container.  I want to have an image and a few lines of text centered in the span.  This works ok.  When I decrease the horizontal size of the window, all of the spans line up in the center of the container.  Is there a way to keep that from happening.  Here's the code:

```
<div class="well" style="padding-bottom:20px">
<div class="container">
<% @novels.each do |novel| %>
    <div class="span3">
        <div align="center"><%= link_to image_tag(novel.cover_thumbnail_url), novel %>
        <br />
        <%= link_to novel.name, novel%><br />
        <%= novel.edition %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little fuzzy on what they symptoms are but maybe this would help.

Have you tried to wrap your whole statement in the center or used style="margin:0 auto" since center is deprecated

[div style="margin:0 auto"]your content here[/div]

Comment: That keeps the spans from centering when I collapse the page, but doesn't center the image and the lines of text.  You gave me some ideas though. Thanks.

Comment: you probably want to use `<div style="text-align: center">` for centering - but when you say `spans` do you mean the `div` tag with `class="span3"` - bootstrap responsive design is supposed to collapse these as the viewport gets smaller - but I think you usually want this  hierarchy of tags `container/row/span`, i.e. `<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="span3">xxxx</div><div class="span9">...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want?

Note use of each_slice, this would result in rows of 3 records per row inside span4

```
<div class="well" style="padding-bottom:20px">
  <div class="container">

    <% @novels.each_slice(3) do |set| %><!-- NOTE: each_slice -->
      <div class="row">

        <% set.each do |novel| %>
          <div class="span4">
            <div style="text-align:center">
              <%= link_to image_tag(novel.cover_thumbnail_url), novel %>
              <br />
              <%= link_to novel.name, novel %>
              <br />
              <%= novel.edition %>
            </div><!-- end center -->
          </div><!-- end span4 -->
        <% end %><!-- end set.each -->

      </div><!-- end row -->
    <% end %>

  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end well -->
```

you would probably want to clean that up to use partials, make it easier to look at

Comment: that's a very good suggestion.  I really like the idea of slices.  Unfortunately it's still displaying the same behavior of all the records collapsing to the center when reduce the horizontal size of the page.

Comment: It is responsive design, you can try to turn it off - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219760/how-do-i-disable-the-responsive-grid-in-bootstrap - but it allows your site to look better on tablets and smart phones