# How do I size content to viewport using the Protostar template of Joomla?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, viewport, joomla3.0

Actuallly, I am new to CSS. When I shrink the window after loading the site on a localhost using protostar template (Joomla 3.3.6), everything gets smashed and looks terrible but looks okay when the window is restored to its full size.

And from some searches, it is likely to look that terrible in mobile devices/phone.

After some more searches and some suggestions, I removed the tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

in the index file but it has yielded nothing.

I found a similar suggestion here (**[How do I disable the "responsive" grid in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219760/how-do-i-disable-the-responsive-grid-in-bootstrap/12220224#12220224)**) but honestly, I can't find **bootstrap-responsive.css** to remove in the protostar template.

Please, is there a way to get this problem solved and what do I have to do to get it done? I would be very, very glad to get any possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

At line 43 of the Protostar template index.php file you have

```
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css');
```

Check out this css file in templates > protostar > css > template.css you'll find what you are after.

Be aware that when you edit a template file like this, it's possible that your changes could be overwritten on Joomla updates, so be sure to keep good backups of what you do.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks very much @David Taiaroa for your response and I appreciate that a lot. Yes, I can see the code in your answer at line 43 but what to do next to solve the problem I'm facing now is the issue. Please, kindly help me with what to do next as I am new to css and I would appreciate that forever. Many thanks!

Comment: I understand that you've removed the viewport meta tag in the HTML which is a start. Make a backup first, then in the CSS file, look for and remove all the @media blocks (lines 4693-5705). That will stop much of the responsive behaviour. It will require some work to get everything working well though. Remember you could always find another, non-reposvie template.

Comment: I appreciate a lot your efforts in trying to help me out. Actually, I have been trying all day, all night with the suggestions and because I already have backups of the index.php and template.css files, I started taking out the media blocks from lines 4693-5705 in bits in the template.css and testing to see the outcome but with no results. Then I later took the courage to remove all the bunch of code from lines 4693-5705 but I couldn't get the desired results. Please, can I get a css code to add to the template.css file which will give the desired results? Many thanks.

Comment: I missed some extra @media blocks lower in the file. Try this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2665617/template.css . If you search your css file, it's ok to have the media print blocks, but delete all the others

Comment: I have had to try the template.css file you posted here but sorry I haven't been able to achieve the desired results. And I wanted to explore more to see what I was doing wrong before replying but so far, I have followed your routine very carefully and can't say what I'm doing wrong that is not getting me the desired results. I'm currently trying my hands on a demo mobile version of the site to see how things pan out. But @David Taiaroa, I'm very grateful and thankful to you for your time. I didn't expect it all. Thanks once again!!!